# Worksheetfunction.sumif returning string

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple worksheetfunction.sumifs in vba and they are calculating correctly, however when I try and stand the

```
worksheetfunction.sumifs val = Application.SumIf(Range("D1:D20"), "" *          "&temp&" * "", Range("C1:C20")) & " , -" & Application.SumIf(Range("E1:E20"), "" * "&temp&" * "", Range("H1:H20")) & " , +" & Application.SumIf(Range("F1:F20"), "" * "&temp&" * "", Range("I1:I20")) & " , -" & Application.SumIf(Range("G1:G20"), "" * "&temp&" * "", Range("J1:J20"))
```

the variable is returned as a string, with the calculation, something like "80-100-0-0-0-0". I would like the worksheetfunction.sumif to actually sum the product of the sumifs. I have tried putting worksheetfunction.sum around the sumifs but to no avail. Any ideas? The reason I am doing this is to not have formulas in a different cell to speed up the very large Excel I am working with. I have also tried doing the sumifs with the ", -" but no joy either.

Comment: in place of `& " , -" &` and ` " , +" &` which is forcing it into a string put `-` and `+` respectively, without any wrapper function.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for editing, I tried doing this and I get like 80-1000000, it does not appear to calculate the applicationsumifs

Comment: is `temp` a variable or are you looking for anything that contains the word "temp"?

Comment: `Val = Application.SumIf(Range("D1:D20"), "* temp *", Range("C1:C20")) - Application.SumIf(Range("E1:E20"), "* temp *", Range("H1:H20")) + Application.SumIf(Range("F1:F20"), "* temp *", Range("I1:I20")) - Application.SumIf(Range("G1:G20"), "* temp *", Range("J1:J20"))`

Comment: Hi Scott, temp is a variable containing the string I am looking for, the sumif is definitely working correctly, because it is returning the correct values, however it is not calculating the values.

Comment: `Val = Application.SumIf(Range("D1:D20"), "* " & temp & " *", Range("C1:C20")) - Application.SumIf(Range("E1:E20"), "* " & temp & " *", Range("H1:H20")) + Application.SumIf(Range("F1:F20"), "* " & temp & " *", Range("I1:I20")) - Application.SumIf(Range("G1:G20"), "* " & temp & " *", Range("J1:J20"))`

Comment: Now I see what you mean, the code is at work, I will definitely try this Monday morning, could you briefly explain why using "* " would work? Note that I would like to add sum and subtract others.

Comment: This is doing that it is W - X + Y - Z

Comment: I tried that but it did not work, firstly the + will be automatically removed, so you can only put -. The new addition in your code above was "* " & temp & " *" why would you put that? The code is working, just not summing the whole at the end.

Answer (score 1):

So I set up my sheet like this:

[image]

Then I ran this code:

```
Sub show()
Dim temp As String
Dim val As Double
temp = "test"
val = Application.SumIf(Range("D1:D20"), "* " & temp & " *", Range("C1:C20")) - Application.SumIf(Range("E1:E20"), "* " & temp & " *", Range("H1:H20")) _
    + Application.SumIf(Range("F1:F20"), "* " & temp & " *", Range("I1:I20")) - Application.SumIf(Range("G1:G20"), "* " & temp & " *", Range("J1:J20"))
Debug.Print val
End Sub
```

The result was 11

[image]

Which when double checking manually, is the correct answer:

[image]

Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Thanks Scott, would you believe I think I forgot to put the comma after the sumifs, omg I feel like an idiot, I am sure this will work! I will let you know on Monday, but until then, I will give you a preemptive thumbs up! Thank you for the help, and sorry for being so neglectful with my syntax.